# Magento : Australian dollar shown as the default currency whereas the default is set to USD

Tags: magento

We have a magento 1.5.1 installed on our server. In that the default currency is set to USD, but somehow, the products are displayed with Australian dollars. I checked in the System > Configuration > Currency Setup and again set the default website and default store view currencies to USD. But, to no avail.'

**EDIT** : I noticed that it's picking the first in the allowed currencies list. I deselected the Australian Dollar and then it started picking British Pound Sterling.

Comment: can someone help me with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it was happening because the earlier developer had written a code which detected the country and respectively selected the country.

Now, since in cases, where the allowed currencies doesn't match one of the countries detected, it defaulted back to first allowed currency.

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure that you it's been set up for your store view? Check your website scope to make sure it's not been set for your store view.

Comment: I have made sure of all things. But, it always picks the AUD as the default display currency. When i deselected the AUD in allowed currencies, it started picking the next in list British Pound Sterling.